# Create intro page MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I want to display an action which hold an introduction and message from manager for few seconds then go to home action

any idea how to achieve that something like the following image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way of achieving this is using the meta refresh tag. Just put the following code into the head of your index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=home.html">
```

Where `5` represents the seconds when the refresh occurs and `url=home.html` is the path where the refresh will redirect.

So in your **index.html** you put introduction content and in **home.html** you build your website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use javascript for this. You can use plain HTML by putting this between the `head` tags on the introduction page. index2.html would be the main page. 5 is the number of seconds before the redirect begins.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=index2.html">
```